# Method to find the height of binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree

Can anybody help me rework this method to find the height of a binary tree. So far my code looks like this, however it is only working for small binary trees. It gives me a NullPointerException when I try to get the size of big trees. I’m not allowed to use any parameters for this task.

```
public int height() {
int leftHeight = 0;
    int rightHeight = 0;
if(this.left != null) leftHeight = this.left.height();
    if(this.right != null) rightHeight = this.right.height();

    if (leftHeight > rightHeight)
        return (leftHeight + 1);
    else
        return (rightHeight + 1); 
}
```

Comment: I don'r see why that would give a NullPointerException.  Please provide an MCVE

Comment: If I have a tree of height 4 on the left side and 0 on the right side it would compare both and then it would add one to the first node, so it would give a height of 2 not 4

Comment: So what are you *really* asking about here?  I thought you were asking about a NullPointerException.  Please provide an MCVE - http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And ... actually ... I don't understand what your comment is saying either.  If the left height is 4 and the right height is 0, then the result >>should be<< 5.  (Not 4.  And I have no idea where you get 2 from.)

Comment: I don't see where this would throw a NPE